# One cohesive question versus several focused questions?

Tags: discussion

When I'm asking questions I am often faced with a choice if I should put all my points in one big question or several small ones.

The points are very much related to one another.

If I put all my points in one, the question is less focused/objective and more likely to turn into a speculative debate.

If I make each point into a separate question, the question would aim at only one thing and it becomes easier to say what is the correct answer. But then you have a lot of clutter.

What is the better approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several focused questions are almost always better.

This allows answers to focus on the problem presented instead of keying in on one aspect of the question. And may allow your individual elements to get better answers than the entire question may have gotten.

It may also be better to stagger the questions over a couple of days just so you don't overwhelm the front page all at once.

Asking several questions is not *always* the best option, but I think that if the problem can be broken down into elements it probably should be.